# What does 'cosmic unfairness' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of 'cosmic unfairness' in the passage below?

> The existential torment and cosmic unfairness of being interested in someone romantically who isn't romantically interested in you.

I was just scrolling web page and came up to this (link to source)
https://qr.ae/pvQlaR

I know the meaning of words used in article but they doesn't seem meaningful

- Existential - Already exist
- Torment - suffering
- Cosmic - space
- Unfairness - injustice

Comment: There is nothing about this sentence that requires an explanation so far as English words and grammatical structures are concerned. The OP is seeking an explanation of the subject matter and the vaguely philosophical presuppositions of the sentence, which is outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

It means "very great unfairness/injustice", as a good dictionary will tell you.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cosmic) has

> **cosmic** *adjective* **2**
>
> : characterized by greatness especially in extent, intensity, or comprehensiveness
>
> *a cosmic thinker*
>
> *a book of cosmic significance*

This appears to be a weakening of the older meaning of *cosmic*: "of or relating to the cosmos, the extraterrestrial vastness, or the universe in contrast to the earth alone". You can see many similar words used to mean very large: [astronomical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astronomical), [galactic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/galactic), and more.

Comment: We don't know the context, so it is quite likely that, as you say, *cosmic* was thrown in here just as an impressive-sounding way of saying very great. It is possible though that, by using that word in this sentence somebody would want to convey the idea that the source of the unfairness is impersonal, that it is not the fault of the person who doesn't reciprocate one's interest, but of the universe being structured so that such disharmony exists in it.

Comment: @jsw29 - Question - Comments are locked on my question. How you was able to comment up on the question ?

Comment: @r15 You took the words out of my mouth. How did jsw29 manage to post a comment under the post? In the meantime, could you add the necessary details and clarifications that I asked in the community-wiki post, please?

Comment: @jsw29 Meta worthy. While this is true, that option does auto populate with "I'm voting to close this question for" for consistent understanding of the comment.  It signals to others that close votes have been initiated for review like "VTC." Those who cannot see the (close votes) might be confused otherwise though your VTC was well worded.  Meta worthy.